# Why does my logger log the same thing multiple times?

Tags: python

I wish to create two different loggers and this is what I have:

```
import logging


def logger(logger_name, level):
    """Create logger with given name and level"""

    # Set up logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # print(logger.handlers)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s %(asctime)s %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Set level
    handler.setLevel(level)

    # Add handlers to logger
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger


LOGGER1 = logger(logger_name='main_app', level=logging.INFO)
LOGGER2 = logger(logger_name='main_app.module', level=logging.DEBUG)

LOGGER1.info('one')
LOGGER2.info('two')
LOGGER1.info('three')
```

This is what is being logged:

```
INFO     2017-01-25 11:49:45,209 one
INFO     2017-01-25 11:49:45,209 two
INFO     2017-01-25 11:49:45,209 two
INFO     2017-01-25 11:49:45,210 three
```

What am I doing wrong here?
How can I prevent `LOGGER2` to log the same thing multiple times?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the attribute `propagate` to `False`, as seen below

```
def logger(logger_name, level):
    """Create logger with given name and level"""

    # Set up logger
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)

    #stops logging messages being passed to ancestor loggers
    logger.propagate = False

    #....
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate);

> If [Logger.propagate] evaluates to true, events logged to this logger will be passed to the handlers of higher level (ancestor) loggers, in addition to any handlers attached to this logger. Messages are passed directly to the ancestor loggers’ handlers - neither the level nor filters of the ancestor loggers in question are considered.

The default value of `logger.propagate` is `True` set by the constructor in `getLogger`.

Note that the name of a logger can be a "period-separated hierarchical values", giving parent-child relationships (as you have done in your two objects `main.app` and `main.app.module`, the latter being the child).

See [Logger Objects section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logger-objects);

> The name is potentially a period-separated hierarchical value, like foo.bar.baz (though it could also be just plain foo, for example). Loggers that are further down in the hierarchical list are children of loggers higher up in the list.